# Clock Jitter and Phase Noise

Tags: noise, phase

I would like to know the impact of the time jitter of the clock driving an ADC on the appearing phase noise while sampling a sine wave. Of course, with strong the clock jitter, the sampled sine wave seems to exhibit more and more phase noise. But how much ?
  Regards,
     Mike

Answer (score 1):

For a sine wave with a period $t_p$ the clock jitter or clock edge time error $t_j$ gives a phase error of $2 \pi t_j/t_p$ radians, where $2\pi$ represents a full period of a sine wave in terms of phase. The period $t_p$ of the sinusoid is an inverse of its frequency $f$, so the phase error can also be written as $2 \pi t_j f$. No matter if *error* is the peak error or the root mean square error, or whatever, as long as it is the same kind for both clock edge time error (jitter) and phase.

Answer (score 1):

There are two sources of sampling jitter in ADCs namely clock jitter and sampler jitter (S/H circuit).

Clock jitter is due to clock imperfections. So if you have an idea sampler, your clock uncertainty will cause jitter in sampling process.
On the other hand, with an ideal a clean clock with no jitter, but an non-ideal sampler, we will still observe jitter. This is due to transistor intrinsic-noise, which would cause deviations from exact sampling time, and is called sampler circuit jitter.
$$\sigma_{system}^2=\sigma_{circuit}^2+\sigma_{clock}^2$$
So sampling jitter is assumed as random deviations of actual sampling instances from desired sampling instances. As shown in following figure these random deviations transform into a random noise in the sampled signal. This noise is proportional to the frequency of input signal and Standard Deviation (s.d) of jitter noise. Authors of [[1](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/50307/)] provided a model to quantify and estimate the jitter noise.

[image]

The model assumes the input signal is a single tone sinusoid sampled with Nyquist-rate. If we assume a variation with Gaussian distribution with a mean of zero and a known standard deviation $\sigma_{jn}$ (based on circuit measurements). Based on their work, the induced jitter noise is directly connected to the s.d of sampling jitter , and slop of the signal at the sampling point $\left.\frac{dV}{dt}\right|_{rms}$, where $V=\cos(2\pi ft)$:

$$e_j=\left.\frac{dV}{dt}\right|_{rms}\times \sigma_{jn}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T\left(\frac{dV(t)}{dt}\right)^2 dt}\times \sigma_{jn}=\sqrt{2} \pi fA\sigma_{jn}$$

where  $A$ is the amplitude of the input sinusoid. Taking into account the jitter noise and the input noise, the SNR of the sampled signal, can be approximated by:

$$SNR_{sampled}=10\log_{10} \left[\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\bigg/\left\{(\sqrt{2} \pi fA\sigma_{jn} )^2+e_i^2\right\} \right] $$

if we consider the input noise (noise in signal before sampling) too small, $(e_i \ll \sqrt{2} \pi fA\sigma_{jn} )$, the above `SNR` formula would simplify to:

$$SNR_{sampled}=-10\log_{10}⁡(2 \pi f \sigma_{jn} )^2 $$

which means how much SNR you loose in terms of jitter magnitude and the signal frequency.

Have a look for details in this paper:

> M. Shinagawa, Y. Akazawa and T. Wakimoto, "Jitter analysis of
> high-speed sampling systems," in IEEE Journal of Solid-State Circuits,
> vol. 25, no. 1, pp. 220-224, Feb 1990.doi: 10.1109/4.50307

Answer (score 0):

Phase noise is just a multiplicative noise affecting the signal. Let the un-distorted signal be $s(t) = e^{2\pi f_0 t}$. In the presence of phase noise:
$$\tilde{s}(t) = s(t)e^{j\epsilon(t)}$$ where $\epsilon(t)$ is a stocahstic random process. Usually, $\epsilon(t) <<1$ then
$$\tilde{s}(t) \simeq s(t) + j\epsilon(t)s(t)$$
which only affects the quadrature-component with respect to the received constellation. In other words, you receive the original signal $s(t)$ and an inteferer $j\epsilon(t)s(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between sampling jitter (which is the rms cycle to cycle variation in time error from the perfect sampling instant for a given samplign rate) and ADC SNR is quantified as:

$$SNR = -20\log(2\pi f_{in} \tau_{rms})$$

As explained in literature references and other posts here. However this relationship is flawed for many applications. This is because jitter  performance as often specified on oscillator datasheets are given as a single quantity and do not take into account the bandwidth and operation of a particular target application. I have referred to this formula and derived SNR's that would result and from that come to the conclusion that a given oscillator will not meet the minimum SNR needed to demodulate a waveform, and found through practice that is not at all the case. Here is why:

Ultimately the phase noise requirement of the clock source is what will provide the complete picture of SNR performance. Phase noise is non-white and specified over a frequency range. The phase noise on the sampling clock translates to noise on our sampled signal, and the amount of noise is the integrated phase noise from a low frequency limit (often the carrier tracking loop bandwidth, or total observation time) to an upper frequency limit (given by the bandwidth of our waveform). From a phase noise measurement we can uniquely and accurately determine the resulting SNR.  In contrast cycle to cycle jitter is the measurement of timing error from one clock edge to the next. The process of measuring cycle to cycle jitter is in effect a high pass filter to the dominant close in phase noise components; consider how the slowest varying components of phase noise will not have changed from one clock edge to the next and so will be attenuated in the cycle to cycle jitter measurement. The cycle to cycle jitter measurement can be predicted by integrating the phase noise with this effective high-pass filter (including the 3 dB increase to the higher frequency offsets due to what becomes an addition of two uncorrelated noise sources in the cycle to cycle measurement). But we cannot predict the phase noise from a cycle to cycle measurement.  The cycle to cycle measurement has included its own high-pass filtering of the phase noise, but disregards the bandwidth range we would be using, and from the cycle to cycle measurement alone (jitter) we have no way of knowing how are application bandwidth would change the result.

Bottom line: use the jitter measurement as quick guidance but a review of the phase noise is necessary to determine suitability of the sampling clock (and resulting SNR) for the given application.

This is detailed further in this related post:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/66519/21048